# Populate SSRS table with child items from XML datasource

Tags: xml, reporting-services

I have an SSRS report that queries data from an XML datasource. I can populate the reports just fine except I'm having trouble with a node in the data that has child items nested in it.

It's something like this:

```
<xml>
    <customer>
        <name>John Smith</name>
        <orders>
            <item>item 1</item>
            <item>item 2</item>
        </orders>
    </customer>
</xml>
```

It's fairly straightforward to use the direct children of customer, but I can't seem to figure out how to access the individual item sub-nodes.

How can I take the contents of orders and put them into a table (or equivalent) on the report?

Comment: Anybody? I've been looking around and it seems like this isn't something that gets addressed.